# Image not uploading in the multipart/for-data form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, multipartform-data, multer

```
const handlesubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
try {
  setshowloader(true);

  const data = {
    en_name: engName,
    hi_name: hiName,
    employeeID: EID,
    AadharNo: aadharNo,
    ContactNo: contactNo,
    employeeStatus: empStatus,
    address: address,
    city: city,
    state: state,
    designation:designation,
    employeeSalary: salary,
    Email: email,
    department: dept,
    joiningDate: joinDate,
    employeeType: emplType,
    BankName: bankName,
    BankBranch: bankBranch,
    IFSC_Code: bankIfsc,
    AccountNo: accNumber,
    AccountHolderName: accHolderName,
    employeePhoto: empPhoto,
  };

  serverInstance( 'hr/add-employee', 'post', data).then((res) => {
    if (res?.status) {
      console.log(res);
      setOpen(false);
      setshowloader(false);
      Swal.fire('Great!', res?.msg, 'success');
      console.log("THis is" + data)
      handleClose()
    }
    if (res?.status === false) {
      setOpen(false);
      setshowloader(false);
      Swal.fire('Error!', res?.msg, 'error');
    }
  });
} catch (error) {
  Swal.fire('Error!', error, 'error');
}
```

};

```
          {step === 1 ?


            (
              <form onSubmit={handleNext}>
                <div className="add-div-close-div">
                  <h2 clssName="add_text_only">Add New Employee</h2>


                  <CloseIcon onClick={() => handleClose()} />

                </div>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>

                  <h3 clssName="add_text_only">Employee Details</h3>
                  <Typography variant="body2" color="primary" align="right" style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
                    {currDate} / {currTime}
                  </Typography>

                </div>
                <div className="flex_div_main_add_user">

                  <div className="main-input-div1">
                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Employee ID*</label>
                      <input

                        id="EID"
                        required

                        placeholder="Enter Employee ID"
                        value={EID}
                        onChange={(e) => setEID(e.target.value)}
                      />

                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Address*</label>
                      <input

                        id="address"
                        required
                        placeholder="Enter Address"
                        value={address}
                        onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                      />

                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Aadhar No.*</label>
                      <input
                        id="payAmt"
                        text="text"
                        required
                        name="payAmt"
                        placeholder='Aadhar No.'
                        value={aadharNo}
                        onChange={(e) => setAadharNo(e.target.value)}
                      />


                    </div>


                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Employee Salary*</label>
                      <input
                        id="salary"
                        text="text"
                        required
                        name="salary"
                        placeholder='Enter Employee Salary'
                        value={salary}
                        onChange={(e) => setSalary(e.target.value)}
                      />


                    </div>


                  </div>

                  <div className="main-input-div2">
                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Contact No.*</label>
                      <input

                        type="text"
                        required
                        placeholder='Enter Contact No.'
                        value={contactNo}
                        onChange={(e) => setContactNo(e.target.value)}
                      />

                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >City</label>
                      <input

                        type="text"

                        placeholder='Enter City'
                        value={city}
                        onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
                      />

                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Department*</label>
                      <Select
                        required
                        sx={{
                          width: '18rem',
                          height: '2rem',
                          borderRadius: '0.5rem',
                          fontSize: 14,
                          '& .MuiSelect-select': {
                            padding: '1px',
                          },
                        }}
                        value={dept}
                        onChange={(e) => setDept(e.target.value)}
                        displayEmpty
                      >
                      <MenuItem disabled value="">Select Department</MenuItem>

                        {deptList && deptList?.map((item, index) => {
                          return (
                            <MenuItem
                              sx={{
                                fontSize: 14,
                              }}
                              key={item.id}
                              value={item?.departmentName_hi}

                            >
                              {item?.departmentName_hi}



                            </MenuItem>
                          )
                        })}

                      </Select>
                    </div>


                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Designation*</label>
                      <Select
                        required
                        sx={{
                          width: '18rem',
                          height: '2rem',
                          borderRadius: '0.5rem',
                          fontSize: 14,
                          '& .MuiSelect-select': {
                            padding: '1px',
                          },
                        }}
                        value={designation}
                        onChange={(e) => setDesignation(e.target.value)}
                        displayEmpty
                      >
                      <MenuItem disabled value="">Select Designation</MenuItem>

                        {designationList && designationList?.map((item, index) => {
                          return (
                            <MenuItem
                              sx={{
                                fontSize: 14,
                              }}
                              key={item.id}
                              value={item?.hi_designation}

                            >
                              {item?.hi_designation}



                            </MenuItem>
                          )
                        })}

                      </Select>

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div className="main-input-div3">

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Employee English Name*</label>
                      <input
                        text="text"
                        id="Name"
                        required
                        name="Name"
                        placeholder="Enter English Name"
                        value={engName}


                        onChange={(e) => setEngName(e.target.value)}
                      />

                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >State</label>
                      <input

                        type="text"

                        placeholder='Enter State'
                        value={state}
                        onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}
                      />

                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Joining Date*</label>
                      <input

                        type="date"
                        required

                        value={joinDate}
                        onChange={(e) => setJoinDate(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>


                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label>Employee Type*</label>
                      <Select
                        required
                        sx={{
                          width: '18rem',
                          height: '2rem',
                          borderRadius: '0.5rem',
                          fontSize: 14,
                          '& .MuiSelect-select': {
                            padding: '1px',
                          },
                        }}
                        value={emplType}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmplType(e.target.value)}
                        displayEmpty
                      >
                      <MenuItem value="" default>Select Leave Type</MenuItem>

                        {emplTypeList && emplTypeList?.map((item, index) => {
                          return (
                            <MenuItem
                              sx={{
                                fontSize: 14,
                              }}
                              key={item.id}
                              value={item?.employeeType_hi}
                              onClick={() => {
                                {


                                }
                              }}
                            >
                              {item?.employeeType_hi}


                            </MenuItem>
                          )
                        })}


                      </Select>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div className="main-input-div4">


                    <div className="inner-input-div2">
                      <label
                        style={{ marginBottom: '0.3rem', marginTop: '1rem' }}
                        htmlFor="categoryname"
                      >
                        Enter Employee Name in Hindi
                      </label>
                      <ReactTransliterate
                        placeholder="Enter Employee Name in Hindi"
                        style={custominput}
                        id="full-name"

                        value={hiName}
                        onChangeText={(hiName) => {
                          setHiName(hiName);
                        }}
                        onChange={(e) => setHiName(e.target.value)}
                        lang="hi"
                      />
                    </div>


                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Email ID*</label>
                      <input

                        text="email"
                        required
                        placeholder='Enter Email ID'
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>


                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Upload Employee Photo*</label>
                     
                      <input
                        accept="image/*"
                        type="file"
                        name="employeePhoto"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setEmpPhoto(e.target.files[0]);
                          console.log(e.target.files[0]);
                        }}
                      />

                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label >Employee Status*</label>
                      <Select

                        sx={{
                          width: '18rem',
                          height: '2rem',
                          borderRadius: '0.5rem',
                          marginTop: '-0.3rem',
                          fontSize: 14,
                          '& .MuiSelect-select': {
                            padding: '1px',
                          },
                        }}

                        style={{ paddingLeft: '1rem' }}
                        value={empStatus}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmpStatus(e.target.value)}
                        displayEmpty
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="" disabled>Select Employee Status</MenuItem>
                        {empStatusList &&
                          empStatusList?.map((item, idx) => {
                            return (

                              <MenuItem
                                sx={{
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                }}
                                key={item.id}
                                value={item?.employeeStatus}
                                onClick={() => {
                                  {


                                  }
                                }}
                              >
                                {item?.employeeStatus}


                              </MenuItem>
                            );
                          })}


                      </Select>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="save-div-btn">
                  <button className="save-div-btn-btn"
                    style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}

                  >
                    {showloader ? (
                      <CircularProgress
                        style={{
                          width: '21px',
                          height: '21px',
                          color: '#FE7600',
                        }}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      'Next'
                    )}
                  </button>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => handleClose()}
                    className="save-div-btn-btn-cancel"
                    type="button"
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            )

            :


            (

              <form onSubmit={handlesubmit} enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div className="add-div-close-div">
                  <h2 clssName="add_text_only">Add New Employee</h2>

                  <CloseIcon onClick={() => handleClose()} />

                </div>

                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>


                  <h3 clssName="add_text_only">Employee Account Details</h3>

                  <Typography variant="body2" color="primary" align="right" style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
                    {currDate} / {currTime}
                  </Typography>

                </div>




                <div className="flex_div_main_add_user" style={{ marginTop: '-1%' }}>




                  <div className="main-input-div2">
                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label htmlFor="Bank Name">Bank Name*</label>
                      <Select
                        required
                        sx={{
                          width: '95%',
                          height: '2rem',
                          borderRadius: '0.5rem',
                          fontSize: 14,
                          '& .MuiSelect-select': {
                            padding: '1px',
                          },
                        }}
                        value={bankName}
                        onChange={(e) => setbankName(e.target.value)}

                      >
                        {
                          bankNameList && bankNameList?.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                              <MenuItem
                                sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}
                                key={item.id}
                                value={item?.bankName}
                              >
                                {item?.bankName}
                              </MenuItem>
                            )
                          })
                        }


                      </Select>
                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label htmlFor="IFSC Code">Bank IFSC Code</label>
                      <input

                        type="text"
                        required

                        placeholder="Enter IFSC Code"
                        value={bankIfsc}
                        onChange={(e) => setBankIfsc(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>


                  </div>
                  <div className="main-input-div2">
                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label htmlFor="Bank Branch">Bank Branch</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        required
                        placeholder="Enter Bank Branch"
                        value={bankBranch}
                        onChange={(e) => setBankBranch(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label htmlFor="Account Number">Account Number</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        required
                        placeholder="Enter Account Number"
                        value={accNumber}
                        onChange={(e) => setAccNumber(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>


                  </div>
                  <div className="main-input-div2">
                   

                    <div className="inner-input-divadd">
                      <label htmlFor="Account Holder's Name">Account Holder's Name</label>
                      <input

                        type="text"
                        required

                        placeholder="Enter Account Holder's Name"
                        value={accHolderName}
                        onChange={(e) => setAccHolderName(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </div>


                  </div>
                </div>



                <div className="save-div-btn" style={{ marginTop: '5%' }}>
                  <button className="save-div-btn-btn"
                    type='submit'

                  >
                    {showloader ? (
                      <CircularProgress
                        style={{
                          width: '21px',
                          height: '21px',
                          color: '#FE7600',
                        }}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      'Submit'
                    )}
                  </button>
                  <button
                    onClick={handleBack}
                    className="save-div-btn-btn-cancel"
                    type="button"
                  >
                    Back
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>

            )}
```

Hello guys...I can't able to upload image in this form I tried multiple things but still the image isn't uploading  in the request payload.I have used multer in the backend to handle image upload.There isn't any error in the backend so there isn't any problem . I think maybe i need to write it in different way as it is multipart/form-data

Answer (score 1):

If you check the request in the 'Network' tab you'll see that you are sending a json object and the requets header is "application/json" which is not what the backend expects.

For the "multipart/form-data" header you should send a FormData object (and it's very easy to do so).

```js
const data = {
    en_name: engName,
    hi_name: hiName,
    employeeID: EID,
    AadharNo: aadharNo,
    ContactNo: contactNo,
    employeeStatus: empStatus,
    address: address,
    city: city,
    state: state,
    designation: designation,
    employeeSalary: salary,
    Email: email,
    department: dept,
    joiningDate: joinDate,
    employeeType: emplType,
    BankName: bankName,
    BankBranch: bankBranch,
    IFSC_Code: bankIfsc,
    AccountNo: accNumber,
    AccountHolderName: accHolderName,
    employeePhoto: empPhoto,
};

const formData = new FormData();

for (const key in data) {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
}
```

The last step is to pass this new `formData` object into the request and the upload should work now.

Comment: I tried what you did but null value is sent in the backend when I submit the form. The request payload is also empty  . When i consolelog the formData it is empty.

Comment: Is the 'data' object also empty? Maybe you're not sending the values in your upload function